Inverse Laplace transform of the Gaussian hypergeometric function $_{2}F_{1}(a,b,;c;x)$
I want to calculate the inverse Laplace transform of the Gaussian hypergeometric function $_{2}F_{1}(a+p,b,;c;-\omega)$ in which
$p$ is the Laplace variable. The inverse Laplace transform is given by
$$
L^{-1}\left\{\overline{F}(P)\right\}=f(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c'-i\infty}^{c'+i\infty} {e^{pt}\overline{f}(p)dp}
$$
For calculating the inverse Laplace transform of $_{2}F_{1}(a+p,b,;c;-\omega)$, using the definition of the Gaussian hypergeometric function, we have
$$
L^{-1}\left\{_{2}F_{1}(a+p,b,;c;-\omega)\right\}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^n\omega^n\Gamma(b+n)\Gamma(c)}{n!\Gamma(b)\Gamma(c+n)}\times \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{c'-i\infty}^{c'+i\infty}{e^{pt}\frac{\Gamma(p+a+n)}{\Gamma(p+n)}dp}}
$$
in which $p=-n-a-m$ and $n,m=0,1,2,\ldots$ and the contour integral in the above equation has one pole.
When it is replaced in the contour integral, according to the denominator of the fraction of the contour integral we have $\Gamma(p+a)=\Gamma(-m-n-a+a)=\Gamma(-m-n)$. Thus the denominator becomes infinite and the answer becomes zero. While the answer to the inverse Laplace transform of the Gaussian hypergeometric function $_{2}F_{1}(a+p,b,;c;-\omega)$, in the book Integrals and Series: Inverse Laplace Transforms by A. P. Prudnikov, is given as
$$
L^{-1}\left\{_{2}F_{1}(a+p,b,;c;-\omega)\right\}=\frac{\Gamma(c)}{\Gamma(b)\Gamma(c-b)}\omega^{1-c}e^{(1-a)x}\times (e^x-1)^{b-1}(1+\omega-e^x)^{c-b-1}
$$
Supposing the above inverse Laplace transform is correct, how can I obtain that?

as a check, you can verify that the formula from Prudnikov is valid for $\omega=-1$, $b=1$, $c=2$, when the hypergeometric function reduces to $(1-a-p)^{-1}$, with inverse Laplace transform $-e^{x-ax}$.

Prudnikov et al. include the conditions $b,p+a\ne0,-1,-2,...$ and $\omega,\operatorname{Re}b,\operatorname{Re}(c-b)>0$ (for convenience, the formula is 3.35.4.1 on page 379 of the 1992 edition)
